# Calculating average number of tries for an event whose probability increases with the number of unsuccesful tries

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value

I have a question that I didn't even know how to word on google.
I have a system where an event has a 2% chance of happening each roll for the first 50 rolls, and, starting from the 51st, its probability increases by 2% each unsuccessful try, so in the 51st try it has a 4% chance, in the 52nd a 6% chance and so on until the 99th in which it has 100% chance, however the chance resets to 2% if the event is rolled.
I have calculated the chance of rolling the event at least once within x number of pulls, for example for 52 pulls it is
$1-( (.98^{50})(.96)(.94) )=.6714$ ,please do correct me if I am wrong.

However I also wanted to know on average how many attempts it would take for the event to occur: I tried reasoning that for an event with a 2% chance it would take on average 50 tries, but that would mean that the increase in probability from the 51st have no weight on this average, and that seemed weird.
In addition, in some instances even if you roll the event there is a **p** chance that the roll still fails; **p** is determined before starting the 1st roll and doesn't change throughout the attempts.

As you can probably imagine I'm not experienced at all in the field (or mathematics in general for the matter) so if it is possible to explain reasonings and calculations in a simple manner I would appreciate.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: On your calculation of rolling the event at least once, please note it is a good approximation but not completely accurate. This is simply because it will also count cases where events happened in both 51st and 52nd roll. Now if the 51st happened, the probability in 52nd reset to 2% (0.98 for not occurring) and it is no longer 0.94.

Comment: Also, it is correct that expected number of rolls to get a success will be $1/0.02 = 50$. If you want to specifically get into changing probability zone, may be you have to look at solving for expected number of rolls for $2$ events to occur.

Answer (score 1):

Here you can apply [Markov Chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain). Probably many different ways.

The most practical ways would probably involve [stochastic matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_matrix) and a sparse matrix of diagonal-like structure.